# How can I fix my issue with onPressed in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter programming and I am having an issue navigating to a new page and getting the onPressed to work correctly. I am using the snippet of code below and I have seen other tutorial videos do the same exact thing, however when I use the snippet everything from "() { Navigator.push( ..... ); }" gets underlined in red with the error:

> Invalid constant value.dart(invalid_constant)

I'm not sure how to fix this error and any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
const ListTile(
              title: Text('About Me'),
              subtitle: Text('Account Information'),
              trailing: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const About()),
                  );
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right_rounded),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: remove const keyword from listTile

Comment: `ListTile(
          title: Text('About Me'),
          subtitle: Text('Account Information'),
          trailing: IconButton(

            icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right_rounded), onPressed: () {  },
          ),
        )` try like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is related to **ListTile onTap property**.

The Widget ListTile already have a definition of onTap, so the onPressed property inside IconButton will **never** be triggered.

Try this:

```
ListTile(
  title: const Text('About Me'),
  subtitle: const Text('Account Information'),
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const About()),
    );
  },
  trailing: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right_rounded,),
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `const`  keyword from `ListTile` .

Now that your list is not static or fixed and it might change or do some action on `onPressed` . So the widget cannot be marked with const
in such case.

This is applicable to all widgets. Dynamic widget would not work with `const`  keyword

```
ListTile(
      title: const Text('About Me'),
      subtitle: const Text('Account Information'),
      trailing: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const About()),
          );
        },
        icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right_rounded),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the keyword `const` near ListTile. If the constructor of `About` is not `const`, remove it also from the `push` method.

Answer (score -1):

As of now, dart function doesn't support constant literal. You are trying to make ListTile a constant constructor but onPressed takes a function as an argument that can not be constant or final. Either remove const from your ListTile or create another static function and then pass it to onPressed.

You can check from the below link.

https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1048

You can also use NavigatorState for navigation.

```
   class MyApp2 extends StatelessWidget {
    
      static final navigatorStateKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
      const MyApp2({Key key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
           key: navigatorStateKey,
           home: ListView(
             children: List.generate(20, (index) =>
                 const ListTile(
                  title: Text('About Me'),
                  subtitle: Text('Account Information'),
                  trailing: IconButton(
                    onPressed:  onPressed,
                   icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right_rounded),
                  ),
                ),
            ),
          ),
        );
    
      }
      static void onPressed() {
        MyApp2.navigatorStateKey.currentState.push( 
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const About()));
       }
      }
```